# Relationship between a DataRobot project and deployment

Tags: datarobot

Does each DataRobot `project` result in a `deployment`?

I got an error message specifying that the number of `deployments` has been reached where the number of `deployments` is much smaller than the number of `projects`. So I was wondering if the expected behavior was to have a `deployment` for each `project` and that was failing because my account can only provision a certain number of `deployments`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no relationship between the number of DataRobot projects to the number of deployments.
The number of deployments depends on the package you purchased. Please reach out to your account team